# Is it possible to kill an app without invoking onPause()?

Tags: android

I understand that saving persistent data in the `onPause()` method is the safest route to saving the data because `onStop()` will not always be called.

However, is it possible that an app is killed without invoking `onPause()` and goes directly to `onStop()`?

Isn't the safest best to save the data in both the `onPause()` **AND** `onStop()` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand when onPause and onStop are actually called.

onPause is called whenever the app is no longer the active Activity (its actually called as soon as its about to no longer be active, but before the next activity is actually started).

onStop is called when the Activity goes totally off screen.

So if onStop is called, onPause will already have been called, short of a framework bug.

As for saving data-  onPause or onStop will generally work.  Generally the rule is just to pair things properly-  onStop with onStart and onPause with onResume.  There are situations where onPause will be called but not onStop, but that's generally because a short term transparent background activity pops up over your app, rather than because onStop will never be called.  So onStop is used more because onPause will cause you to save more frequently than needed.

Comment: Thanks, but I think CommonsWare may have the right answer.

Comment: @the_prole He does.  We're saying the same thing, I'm explaining why that is.

Answer (score 1):

> However, is it possible that an app is killed without invoking onPause() and goes directly to onStop()?

No. If `onStop()` is called, it is guaranteed that `onPause()` will have been called.

Answer (score 0):

No, the onPause() method will always be executed. It's the only method that is guaranteed to be called when your activity loses focus, is stopped or is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

No. Any time your app goes into the background or you change the activity onPause will be triggered. There is no scenario where onPause is not called but onStop is.

If your app crashes, neither of two will be called.